# Buttons for Navigation” and “GPS Pointer” are not visible when I click on a marker

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a google map with custom info window. Also I added some logic for centering the info window when the marker/pin is clicked. From what I have read the problem is with overriding the `setOnMarkerClickListener`. Although I set explicitly `mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);` 
It’s not working. Here is my code:

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

            // Description: Get device height
            // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            int height = size.y;

            // Description: Move the camera up so title of info window is visible
            // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            LatLng markerLocation = marker.getPosition();
            Point mappoint = mMap.getProjection().toScreenLocation(new LatLng(markerLocation.latitude, markerLocation.longitude));
            mappoint.set(mappoint.x, mappoint.y - (height / 3));

            CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(mMap.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(mappoint));

            mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);

            mMap.animateCamera(cu, new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    if (marker != null) {

                        marker.showInfoWindow();

                        mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                }
            });

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem, Return false on your onMarkerClick so that the default behavior would be displayed.